# Is there a version of a Mootools Auto-collapsing breadcrumb like the jBreadCrumb plugin for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, mootools, breadcrumbs

Is there a version of a Mootools Auto-collapsing breadcrumb like the jBreadCrumb plugin for jQuery?

http://www.comparenetworks.com/developers/jqueryplugins/jbreadcrumb.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there's a "plugin" to do just this - try looking in the official plugin repository.

Anyway, just for the fun of it, I've written a very basic script to replicate the behavior you're looking for. See the example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/oskar/nTHv2/

Comment: sweet - although i dont like the original ui, it's quirky. another thing that is wrong is the markup, for google to recognise the breadcrumb for what it is, <a href=''>home</a> > <a href=''>products</a> > ... works better. this should also use the SEO friendly markup and come as a progressive enhancement on top. anyway, well done +1

Comment: So far this seems to be fine. Thanks for the post!